# Find the conjugacy classes of $D_6$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am following an example in my lecture notes, but I have come to a part which I cannot get to work for myself. Thanks.

Find the conjugacy classes of $D_6$.
Take $$G = D_6 = \langle a,b \mid a^3 =b^2 = 1, ab = ba^{2}\rangle = \{1,a,a^2,b,ab,a^2b\}.$$

Then $e^G = \{e\}$.

I have found the conjugacy classes of $a^G=\{a,a^2\}$.

And I am now finding them for $b^G$

so far I have got;

$e^{-1}be=b$

$a^{-1}ba = ab$

but for $(a^2)^{-1}ba^2$ I cannot get the answer my lecture notes has of $a^2b$.

I also cannot get $(a^2b)^{-1}ba^2b$ to work either, my lecture notes say this is $ab$, but I cannot obtain this result.

I am sure it's really silly but I am going round in circles and wasting my time! Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the last relation in the definition of $G$ be $ba=a^{-1}b$? [From $ba=a^{-1}$ we have $b=a^{-2}$ and then eventually $G$ is abelian.]

Comment: Can you show your work on how you arrived at $a^{-1}ba = ab$? The other two equalities are correct and should be similarly hard. (Also note as coffemath pointed out that the relations might have been messed up, I fixed them.)

Comment: In the question I am given ab=b$a^2$

Comment: For $a^{-1}ba = ab$, we know $a^{-1}b=ba$ so $a^{-1}ba=baa=ba^2=ab$??

Comment: @PeterPatzt my question gives me $ab=ba^2$ not $ba=a^{-1}b$

Answer (score 0):

Note that conjugating by $a^2$ is the same as conjugating by $a$ twice. And you know how to conjugate by $a$ in $D_6$. In general, it is useful to denote generators of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ (symmetries of a regular $n$-gon) by $r$ and $s$, with $$D_{2n}=\langle r,s\mid r^n=s^2=1,srs=r^{-1}\rangle$$

These remind you that $r$ is a *rotation* (by an angle $2\pi/n$) and $s$ is a *symmetry* across the first vertex. Note $s=s^{-1}$, so $srs=srs^{-1}=r^{-1}$ tells you that conjugation by $s$ flips inverts $r$.  You have  $$D_{6}=\langle r,s\mid r^3=s^2=1,srs=r^{-1}\rangle=\{1,r,r^2,s,rs,r^2s\}$$

So, let's say you have to find the class of $s$. It is clear $s$ and $1$ fix $s$. Then

$$r^{-1}sr=r^{-1}sr(ss)=r^{-1}(srs)s=r^{-1}r^{-1}s=rs=r^{-1}s=r^2s$$

Since conjugating $s$ by $r^2$ is the same as conjugating by $r$ twice, $r^{-2}sr^2=r^{-1}(rs)r=sr$. Then 
$$(rs)^{-1}srs=sr^{-1}(srs)=sr^{-1}r^{-1}=sr$$

$$(r^2s)^{-1}sr^2s=(sr^{-2})(sr^2s)=(sr)(srs)(srs)=sr r^{-1}r^{-1}=sr^{-1}=(sr^{-1}s)s=rs$$

Comment: In my lecture notes we have that $(ab)^{-1}bab=a^2b$ but you obtained that is is sr (so ba)??

Comment: @ZZS14 Note that $(ab)^{-1}bab=b^{-1}a^{-1}bab=ba^{-1}bab=ba^{-1}a^{-1}=ba^{-2}=ba=a^2b$.